# AuthorizeNet In-Person SDK: Unable to Void a credit card transactions

Tags: authorize.net

I have an application that uses the Authorize.Net In-Person SDK (using a bbpos reader) to charge credit cards.

I can charge credit cards without any issue. However, I am unable to implement the Void transaction.

When creating the request, I set

```
 transactionRequestType transaction = new transactionRequestType()
{
    transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.voidTransaction.ToString(),
    refTransId = "<my transaction Id>"
};
```

I tried invoking each of the following with SDKTransactionType set to SDKTransactionType.VOID

1. startQuickChipTransaction
2. startQuickChipWithoutUI
3. startEMVTransaction

None of the 3 above options worked, and there is no error thrown. Control returns to the program silently.

I do not find documentation anywhere regarding this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by bypassing the In-Person SDK altogether, and following the approach shown in:
https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-void-a-transaction